# SSH/SFTP Hopping: Opening a prompt within the authentication process

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, proxy

I am currently working on a way to allow server based (more or less)-transparent SSH-Hopping.

Lets say I have three hosts:

SSH-Source (192.168.200.40)
   SSH-Proxy  (192.168.134.40)
   SSH-Target (192.168.135.40)

To connect to SSH-Target from SSH-Source I need to hop over the SSH-Proxy.
However I dont want any ssh configuration to be done on the SSH-Source.

For this I configured my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the SSH-Proxy as described in the following article:
http://blog.lick-me.org/2012/06/ssh-gateway-shenanigans/

```
command="bash -c 'ssh user@SSH-Target ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-}'" ssh-rsa AAAAB3
```

However, this setup is pretty static and for my use I want to get it more flexible because I want to use my SSH-Proxy to connect to many accounts on different hosts by always using the same RSA-Key to connect to any target server.

For now I am trying to replace the static "user@host" part with a script which prompts the user to type in a new host or username to connect to the target server.

So this is the way I would change my authorized_keys.

```
command="bash -c 'ssh user@`host.sh`${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:-}'"
```

This means host.sh will by replaced with SSH-Target(192.168.135.40) which will be returned out of `host.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
message="192.168.135.40"
echo $message
```

This works fine but as I'm tying to use a bash script which interacts with the user I'm not getting any further.

So this is what I tried to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter Host: "
read adresse
echo $adresse
```

So my SSH-Proxy is reading the content of my script instead of opening a new bash.

```
user@SSH-Source:~$ ssh user@192.168.134.40
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
bash: Enter: command not found
Connection to 192.168.134.40 closed
```

So my question is to know if it is possible to open a new bash in this "authentication process" which opens the script returns a value and closes again. Also this prompt should be shown using WinSCP.

Or maybe there is a much better way?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use the first `ProxyCommand` option? That should let you configure this per-remote-host on the client side just fine.

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick answer. For my understanding this would be on my SSH-Source. Host SSH-Target
  ProxyCommand ssh -q 192.168.134.40 nc -q0 192.168.135.40 22 .. This worked but i need the Proxy function to be done on my SSH-Proxy

Comment: The bit you list on the `ProxyCommand` line *is* run on the proxy host via ssh. That's what that `ssh` command is doing. You are telling the local ssh to run `ssh -q 192.168.134.40 nc -q0 192.168.135.40 22` as your proxy command. Which, in turn, is logging you in to that host and running that specified command.

Comment: I could use this command to connect to my server yes but I want to user something like ssh@192.168.134.40 and I should be automatically forwarded to 192.168.135.40 which works perfectly in the setup above as long as I keep logging in with "user"

Comment: That's what using `ProxyCommand` gets you with the right setup. You just ssh into the target and the ssh config (with `ProxyCommand`) takes care of the proxy jumping. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes but for this I have to configure the ProxyCommand on my SSH-Source. So I can use the "ssh user@SSH-Target" and it works. But this is not what I need.

Comment: I don't understand. What about `ProxyCommand` isn't what you want?

Comment: My setup needs to be transparent. Let´s say I have 50 Users and 20 Hosts. So i would have to do 20 entries on 50 User-PCs which would also be static

Comment: I'd prefer a static config that needed to be written once to being forced to input the right host every time I wanted to ssh (after writing the initial ssh command to the proxy already) but *shrug*. You could always right a `myssh` (or something) script which handles some of this for you through arguments (and writes out temporary ssh config files or something).